# How to get selection from optical form?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm writing an optical form reader using Python and OpenCV. I crop the answer from the optical form, but how can I know which selection is filled?

Here's an example image:

[image]

Here's my code so far:

```py
image = cv2.imread('cevap1.png')
image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(1,1),0)
th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 1)][1]][1]
```

Comment: can ı use similarity algorithm ? for exampla A.png is %90 similar with answer1.png then answer1.png is selection A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming answers are characterized by mostly filled circles, I would just sum all pixel values row-wise. Then, split the resultig vector in five parts, each representing the summed values for one of the options, and average the intensity values within these windows. The window with the lowest mean intensity is then the selected answer (dark colors = low intensity values).

I will give an example code snippet for detecting a single answer:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read image
img = cv2.imread('images/p4I1m.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Sum intensity values row-wise
sum = np.sum(img, axis=0)
plt.plot(sum)
plt.show()

# Set up answers
nAnswers = 5
answers = []

# Calculate mean intensity value for each answer option using a simple windowed, moving average with displacement
step = int(np.floor(sum.size / nAnswers))
for i in range(nAnswers):
    answers.append(np.mean(sum[i*step:(i+1)*step-1]))
print(answers)

# Find minimum mean intensity
answer = np.argmin(answers)
print(answer)

# TODO: Mapping from indices (0, 1, ...) to ('A', 'B', ...)
```

Output of the plot:

[image: Plot]

Output of `answers`:

```
[2225.0, 2227.5454545454545, 2252.909090909091, 2246.0, 1449.3636363636363]
```

Output of `answer`:

```
4
```

I skipped the mapping from the result of `np.argmin` to something like A, B, etc.

Now, further improvements are needed:

- Empty answers: All mean values will be similar. You would need some kind of threshold for "filled" or "not filled" to check against.
- Multiple answers: More than one mean value will be significantly larger than the others. Again, thresholds might be the better option to distinguish between "filled" or "not filled".

The row-wise summation should be robust to rotation to a certain degree.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you so much its worked. and thanks for my posts edit :))